# BLE c# Write Characteristic

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating an integration with a BLE device in c #, I already have the code to connect to subscribe and send values

Device

Smart scale body composition

App

Winform library Windows.Devices.Bluetooth lastest version

but I do not know how I should send them

utf8? utf16? hex? binary?

I attached a screenshot of the log that I got from wireshark

Thanks

[Log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DePtq.png)

Comment: Without knowing What BLE device you use this is impossible to answer, but it will always be a byte array.  It can be any kind of coding. The way of sending this array also depends on the type of the application you are writing the code for(Windows forms, WPF, UWP etc. So give more information.

Comment: Is a Winform, Windows.Devices.Bluetooth library latest version, the device is a srmart scale body composition

Comment: If you don't know the communication protocol for the device it is almost impossible.
Every device has its own. Data can be bigEndian or litleEndian . 
A data package can range from 1 to 20 bytes and can contain a checksum or not.
A typical package to set time can be something like this:
 
0:  packet start(1 byte)
1: total packet length (1 byte)
2: command(1byte)
3-7:Unix time (4 bytes)
08: checksum